# How can I rescue geocoder query limit error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-geocoder, rails-geocoder

I have the following code in my model

```
geocoded_by :street_address
```

And in some point I do

```
place.geocode
```

How can I identify if the geocoder error limit is reached? I'm not getting any exception, just the following message is printed: `Google API error: over query limit.`

Also, how do I do this if the geocode is triggered not directly but by a callback?

Thank you very much!

Comment: On checking the source code of [`geocoder` gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/master/lib/geocoder/exceptions.rb#L11), this exception is handled by a class `OverQueryLimitError`. You can rescue the exceptions from this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out I needed to generate the geocoder config file with:

`rails generate geocoder:config`

and add the line:

`always_raise: [Geocoder::OverQueryLimitError]`.

Then in my code rescue the exception:

```
def my_method
  place.geocode
rescue Geocoder::OverQueryLimitError
  puts('The geocoder limit has been reached.')
end
```

I haven't figured out yet how to do it from a callback.